# Is a set "trapped" between two convex sets, convex?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $A, C$ be two strictly-convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $B$ be a set such that:

$$A\subseteq B\subseteq C.$$

Is $B$ strictly-convex too? Not necessarily. For example, $A$ and $C$ can be to concentric discs, and $B$ can be a crazy amoeba-shaped figure trapped between them:

[image]

But what if $A$ and $C$ only differ in their boundary? Consider two cases:

- $A$ is the interior of some set and $C$ is the closure of the same set. Then, as shown by Anonymous below, $B$ might be arbirary
- $A$ is the interior of $C$ and $C$ is the closure of $A$, so that $B$ contains $A$ plus some part of the boundary. In this case, is $B$ always strictly-convex?

Comment: no it's not convex, draw a full square and remove one of edges except the two end points, if we consider $B$ to be this shell without the last edge, it's still not convex.

Comment: But the full square is not strictly convex (because points on the sides are not in the interior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C$ be closed and strictly convex with $int \ C \ne \emptyset$. Let $B$ be such that
$$
int \ C \subset B \subset C.
$$
The interior of a set is an open set, so $int\ C \subset int \ B$.

Then $B$ is strictly convex: let $x,y\in B \subset C$. Then $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in int \ C\subset int \ B$ for $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

As stated, this is false.

In $R^3$, let $C = \bar{B}(0,1)$ and let $D = C \cap Q^3$. Then $C$ is the closure of $D$ and the interior $A$ of $D$ is empty. There are many non-convex bodies $B$ contained in $C$.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not state correctly what I meant... What I meant was that A is the interior of C and C is the closure of A, so that B contains A plus some part of the boundary. In this case, is B always strictly-convex?